# How to show Personal reading rate?

Tags: 7, users

I use view & seen module make a bulletin .

How can I survey user "reading rate", I want to know:

- if everyone read every article, or
- which article specific person do not read yet.

Any help?

Comment: Can you add the hyperlinks to the modules you're using? Is it https://www.drupal.org/project/seen ? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module seems like a no brainer to me to get this to work. Combine it with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to have a custom (not global) flag automatically flag such article, based on whatever rules Event that would fit. And since Flags are fieldable, you could even add an extra field to it to let your user indicate some type of rating, if that's what you want.